# Python converting string to time

Tags: python

I have the following string `20200424003000 +0200` where '20200424 is the date (YYYYMMDD) and 003000 is the time (HHMMSS) and +0200 is the UTC timezone.

I'd like to convert that string another format, being `2020-04-24 00:30:00`.
Can someone point me in the good direction for doing so ?

Comment: @deceze timezone will always be UTC +2 so yes

Comment: Should I split string after 2020 and then match any number and join it with - to get output of 2020-04-24 ?

Comment: try this https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html , ignore my previous.

Comment: Always try to use the python docs and see examples, try by your self, please add the code here, lot of people will be able to help. Everyone will learn something. good luck !

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in library can do the job.

```py
import datetime

datetime_str = '20200424003000 +0200'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S %z')
print(dt)
```

You can learn more about `strptime` and generallty date-time formatting in Python [here](https://strftime.org/).

Comment: That's gonna help a lot thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your string into a datetime object so you can leverage all avantages that come with a datetime object, eg formatting, timedelta etc.

```
from datetime import datetime

your_date_str = '20200424003000 +0200'

# The formatting string includes timezone (%z)
date_object = datetime.strptime(your_date_str , "%Y%m%d%H%M%s %z")
print("date_object: {}".format(date_object))
```

Comment: The string doesn't contain any microseconds. The time is 03:00:00.

Comment: Indeed, read too fast ;) Corrected

Answer (score 1):

It looks like task for `datetime.datetime.strptime` - which is function accepting string and [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and return `datetime.datetime` object, in your case:

```
import datetime
t = '20200424003000 +0200'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S %z')
```

Then you might use `strftime` method, which accept only format string to get `str` you want. For example you can get `YYYY-MM-DD` by:

```
yyyymmdd = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(yyyymmdd)  # 2020-04-24
```